# How can I see what Google Chrome is currently downloading?

Tags: google-chrome, download

I downloaded a lot of stuff using the download master extension for Google Chrome. I thought it was done downloading but when I want to close the browser, I get this Alert:

[image]

This concerns me a bit. How can I see exactly which downloads are "currently in progress"? There's tons of them in the download tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>) and I can't seem to sort them by status or anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to clear finished downloads. If you want them to auto-clear, try this extension:

[Always Clear Downloads](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-clear-downloads/cpbmgiffkljiglnpdbljhlenaikojapc)

Comment: cool, that seems a perfect solution to this problem!